# Gathering segmented data via jQuery with FOR loops

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, for-loop

Here's my code (what I'm stuck on is after the jump)

```
<script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
var countThisMany = 4; //how many data-id's I want to count per "section" of images
var finalString = "";  //blank var to be used later, must be defined here.
</script>

<img src="foo.jpg" data-id="id1" data-item="1" />    // just a bunch
<img src="foo.jpg" data-id="id2" data-item="2" />    // of images with
<img src="foo.jpg" data-id="id3" data-item="3" />    // data-* usage to
<img src="foo.jpg" data-id="id4" data-item="4" />    // store two bits
<img src="foo.jpg" data-id="id5" data-item="5" />    // of information
<img src="foo.jpg" data-id="id6" data-item="6" />    // that I'll need
<img src="foo.jpg" data-id="id7" data-item="7" />    // to extract
<img src="foo.jpg" data-id="id8" data-item="8" />    // later on below.

<img src="bar.jpg" data-id="id9" data-item="1" />    // another set of images
<img src="bar.jpg" data-id="id10" data-item="2" />
<img src="bar.jpg" data-id="id11" data-item="3" />
<img src="bar.jpg" data-id="id12" data-item="4" />
<img src="bar.jpg" data-id="id13" data-item="5" />
<img src="bar.jpg" data-id="id14" data-item="6" />
<img src="bar.jpg" data-id="id15" data-item="7" />
<img src="bar.jpg" data-id="id16" data-item="8" />

<script type="text/javascript">
var item_array = $("img").map(function() {
    return $(this).attr("data-item");
}).get();

//alert(item_array);
//returns "1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8"


var id_array = $("img").map(function() {
    return $(this).attr("data-id");
}).get();
//alert(id_array);
//returns "id1,id2,id3,id4,id5,id6,id7,id8,id9,id10,id11,id12,id13,id14,id15,id16"


for (i=0;i<countThisMany;i++){
finalString=finalString+id_array[i]+';';
}

//alert(finalString);
//returns "id1;id2;id3;id4" -- could be more or less if "countThisMany" is changed to something other than 4 

</script>
```

This entire code is self-contained so feel free to save it as an HTML and uncomment the alerts to see the results.

What I need, however, is a step further.  I would like to only collect the `data-id` of the `img` tags whose `data-item` are less than or equal to the variable `countThisMany`

So the end result of `finalString` would be "id1;id2;id3;id4;id9;id10;id11;id12".  And if `countThisMany` was changed to 2, for instance, it would be "id1;id2;id9;id10"

I feel as though I am *so close* but I can't figure out how to only gather the first 4 of the first set of 8 images, and the first 4 of the second set of 8 images.  Again, the total amount of images and how many I would need to capture vary, hence the "countThisMany' var.

This is my first post to the amazing stackoverflow community, so I'm excited!  Thanks to all contributors ahead of time!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `filter` method

```
var item_array = $("img").filter(function() {
    return parseInt($(this).data("item")) <= countThisMany;
}).map(function() {
    return $(this).data('id');
}).get();
```

Comment: After investigating further, I'm realizing this is the best answer and that it suits what I need very well.
Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/5yNbE/6/
Thank you!

Comment: @Tomalak - I looked into the radix parameter and couldn't figure out how I would include it in this parseInt that I have.  It would be X in the following, right?: parseInt(x,$(this).data("item")) -- but in my case, I'm unsure exactly what I would need to put, as I'm not totally sure what radix does.

Comment: @dfsq, thank you -- is 10 just an arbitrary number then? or what purpose is it for?

Comment: @Scott It means "base 10" (i.e. decimal numbers). If you don't use that, `parseIn('010')` will be interpreted as octal, giving `8`. This can lead to unexpected bugs. `parseInt('010', 10)` gives `10`. Note that `parseFloat()` always is base 10.

Answer (score 0):

```
var countThisMany = 4;
var item_array = $("img")
    .filter(function() {
       return parseFloat( $(this).attr("data-item") ) <= countThisMany;
    })
    .map(function() {
       return $(this).attr("data-id");
    })
    .toArray(); /* instead of get() */
```

Note that this will return an array. You seem to want a string, so you might want to call `.join(',')` on the result.

Answer (score 0):

Use `$.grep` in combination with `$.map`.  I also added a `join` to array rather than the loop. fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/brentmn/5yNbE/5/

```
var countThisMany = 2;
var finalString = "";

var id_array = $.grep($('img'), function(item) {
    return ($(item).data('item') <= countThisMany);
}).map(function(item) {
    return $(item).data('id')
});

finalString = id_array.join(';');
```